# Hey, I was wondering how do I stop my code from repeating the same value when i hold down a button in my function?

Tags: c

## main code

```
while(1){// my while loop in my main function
        ch = ReadKeyPad(ch);

        if (ch == '*') i *= 100;
        else if (ch == '#') {
            i = 0;
            ezLCD_ClearDisplay(lcd);
        }
        else if (ch >='0' && ch <= '9') i = i*10 + (ch - '0');

        sprintf(str, "%d   ", i);
        ezLCD_Position(lcd, 0, 0);
        ezLCD_PrintString(lcd, str);

        timer_waitMillis(100);
    }
```

- problem
- I tried comparing my ch value given from main function to my key value inputed
- for some reason it is not reading my ch value or I think i cant use ch == key to compare two char values

## Function

```
char ReadKeyPad(char ch)
{
    char matrixkeys[4][4] = // my button keypad values
    {   {'1','2','3','A'},
        {'4','5','6','B'},
        {'7','8','9','C'},
        {'*','0','#','D'}
    };
    int     row = 1;
    int     col;
    char    key = 0x00;
        uint32_t *R1 = (uint32_t*) ((char*)GPIOB + ((_PIN0) <<2));
        uint32_t *R2 = (uint32_t*) ((char*)GPIOB + ((_PIN1) <<2));
        uint32_t *R3 = (uint32_t*) ((char*)GPIOE + ((_PIN4) <<2));
        uint32_t *R4 = (uint32_t*) ((char*)GPIOE + ((_PIN5) <<2));

        uint32_t *C1 = (uint32_t*) ((char*)GPIOB + ((_PIN4) <<2));
        uint32_t *C2 = (uint32_t*) ((char*)GPIOA + ((_PIN5) <<2));
        uint32_t *C3 = (uint32_t*) ((char*)GPIOA + ((_PIN6) <<2));
        uint32_t *C4 = (uint32_t*) ((char*)GPIOA + ((_PIN7) <<2));

    for (row = 1; row < 5; row++)
    {
        switch(row){
            case 1:
                *R1 = 0x00;*R2 = 0xFF; *R3 = 0xFF; *R4 = 0xFF;
                 timer_waitMillis(10);
                if(((*C1) & _BIT4) == 0) key = matrixkeys[0][0];
                if(((*C2) & _BIT5) == 0) key = matrixkeys[0][1];
                if(((*C3) & _BIT6) == 0) key = matrixkeys[0][2];
                if(((*C4) & _BIT7) == 0) key = matrixkeys[0][3];
                break;
            case 2:
                *R1 = 0xFF;*R2 = 0x00; *R3 = 0xFF; *R4 = 0xFF;
                 timer_waitMillis(10);
                if(((*C1) & _BIT4) == 0) key = matrixkeys[1][0];
                if(((*C2) & _BIT5) == 0) key = matrixkeys[1][1];
                if(((*C3) & _BIT6) == 0) key = matrixkeys[1][2];
                if(((*C4) & _BIT7) == 0) key = matrixkeys[1][3];
                break;
            case 3:
                *R1 = 0xFF;*R2 = 0xFF; *R3 = 0x00; *R4 = 0xFF;
                 timer_waitMillis(10);
                if(((*C1) & _BIT4) == 0) key = matrixkeys[2][0];
                if(((*C2) & _BIT5) == 0) key = matrixkeys[2][1];
                if(((*C3) & _BIT6) == 0) key = matrixkeys[2][2];
                if(((*C4) & _BIT7) == 0) key = matrixkeys[2][3];
            break;
            case 4:
                *R1 = 0xFF;*R2 = 0xFF; *R3 = 0xFF; *R4 = 0x00;
                 timer_waitMillis(10);
                if(((*C1) & _BIT4) == 0) key = matrixkeys[3][0];
                if(((*C2) & _BIT5) == 0) key = matrixkeys[3][1];
                if(((*C3) & _BIT6) == 0) key = matrixkeys[3][2];
                if(((*C4) & _BIT7) == 0) key = matrixkeys[3][3];
            break;
        }
```

-I feel like I could check it here since before I break out ofmy loop I could check the value then i could return a blank value which is 0x00

```
        if(key != 0) {
            if(ch == key)
            key = 0x00;
            break;
        }
    }
    return key;
}
```

Comment: What keypad/CPU are you using? Do you have key-pressed and/or key-released signals you can wire up to an interrupt?

Comment: can you edit the code to provide what you returning from `ReadKeyPad()` and as well what is `i` ?

Comment: Does your keyboard provide debounce and roll-over filtering or are you reading a raw input matrix?

Comment: Wait for the button to be un-pressed before you repeat the loop?

Comment: Sorry I jsut saw these comments. The keypad I'm using is a 4x4 matrix keypad. my i value is the value that is being displayed on my lcd display. And my professor told us that we should be able to only edit the function code to make our buttons only register once.

Comment: What confuses me is I don't get how to store a value like temp to compare my previous inputed key to my current key since it is in a function. And the function should help read read the button pressed as only one input even if the user has held down the button, but if the press the button and then release it and then press the button again, the key should now register 2 inputs since the user has released the button and repressed it. I'm sorry if im not explaining this very well :(

Comment: For part one look up static variables.  For part two you'll have to assume that your function will be called at a faster rate than the button can be pressed.

Comment: Addressing one detail of your question: it is absolutely standard and routine to compare `char` values via the `==` operator.  There are no particular surprises inherent in doing so.

Comment: On a separate note, you do not want to blindly suppress duplicate keypresses, because these can be valid inputs.  For instance, what if I want to enter the number "11"?  Furthermore, what if no key is currently pressed when your `ReadKeyPad()` function is called?  It looks like you'll end up returning a garbage value.

Comment: Overall, then, it appears your concept is mismatched to your need.  You don't want a function that merely reads what key is currently pressed; rather you want a function that *waits* for a key to be pressed, then waits again for it to be released, and ultimately returns a value characteristic of the key that was pressed.

Comment: Hmm I think I understand what you are saying I remember doing that for an led for one of my other codes. Thank you :). And for the code could I use an if statement before the break for each of my switch cases? Like do not break out unless C2 != 0?